# How to get the question to loop if the user input is incorrect

Tags: java, loops

Whenever the user enters data that is incorrect, the program puts out a message telling the user to try again, but it then goes back to the main menu instead of letting the user try an input a different value. How can I do this?

```
public void createStudentRecord(Scanner in)
{
    inputStudentID = null;
    inputMark = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter Student ID: ");
    in.nextLine();
    inputStudentID = in.nextLine();
    if (!(inputStudentID.length()==6))
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a student ID that is 6 characters");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Enter Module Mark: ");
        inputMark = in.nextInt();
        if (inputMark <0 || inputMark >100)
        {
            System.out.println("PLease enter a module mark between 0-100");
        }
        else
        {
            addStudent(inputStudentID, inputMark);
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("New student record has been " + 
                        "successfully created");
            System.out.println();
            countRecords();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can change your `if` to a `while` and pull the remaining code out of the `else`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is by looping until you see the correct/desired input. One problem with this kind of approach is that it will never terminate if user doesn't enter the expected values (if this is what you are looking for),

**Code Snippet:**

```
public void createStudentRecord(Scanner in) {
    String inputStudentID = null;
    int inputMark = 0;

    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Enter Student ID: ");
        inputStudentID = in.nextLine();
        if (!(inputStudentID.length() == 6)) {
            System.out.println("Enter a student ID that is 6 characters");
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Enter Module Mark: ");
        inputMark = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
        if (inputMark < 0 || inputMark > 100) {
            System.out.println("PLease enter a module mark between 0-100");
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    addStudent(inputStudentID, inputMark);
    System.out.println("\nNew student record has been successfully created.\n");
    countRecords();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I would go about solving this problem. The first is to loop on each variable until a valid response is given.

```java
public void createStudentRecord(Scanner in)
{
    inputStudentID = null;
    inputMark = -1;

    while (inputStudentID == null)
    {
      System.out.println("Enter Student ID: ");
      inputStudentID = in.nextLine();
      if (inputStudentID.length() != 6)
      {
          System.out.println("Enter a student ID that is 6 characters");
          inputStudentID = null;
      }
    }

    while (inputMark == -1)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter Module Mark: ");
        inputMark = in.nextLine();
        if (inputMark < 0 || inputMark > 100) {
            System.out.println("PLease enter a module mark between 0-100");
            inputMark = -1;
        }
    }

    addStudent(inputStudentID, inputMark);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("New student record has been successfully created");
    System.out.println();
    countRecords();
}
```

The second is to use recursion.

```java
public void createStudentRecord(Scanner in)
{
    inputStudentID = null;
    inputMark = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter Student ID: ");
    inputStudentID = in.nextLine();
    if (inputStudentID.length() == 6)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a student ID that is 6 characters");
        createStudentRecord(in);
        return;
    }

    System.out.println("Enter Module Mark: ");
    inputMark = in.nextLine();
    if (inputMark < 0 || inputMark > 100)
    {
        System.out.println("PLease enter a module mark between 0-100");
        createStudentRecord(in);
        return;
    }

    addStudent(inputStudentID, inputMark);
    System.out.println("\nNew student record has been successfully created\n");
    countRecords();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the if-else statement to while statement.

```
public static void createStudentRecord(Scanner in)
{
    inputStudentID = null;
    inputMark = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter Student ID: ");
    in.nextLine();
    inputStudentID = in.nextLine();

    while (!(inputStudentID.length()==6))
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a student ID that is 6 characters");
    }

    System.out.println("Enter Module Mark: ");
    inputMark = in.nextInt();
    while (inputMark <0 || inputMark >100)
    {
        System.out.println("PLease enter a module mark between 0-100");
    }
    addStudent(inputStudentID, inputMark);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("New student record has been " + 
                "successfully created");
    System.out.println();
    countRecords();

}
```

Also, you can set a timeout variable to define the max number of times that user can try again. Such like,

```
public static void createStudentRecord(Scanner in)
{
    int timeout1 = 3, timeout2 = 3;

    inputStudentID = null;
    inputMark = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter Student ID: ");
    in.nextLine();
    inputStudentID = in.nextLine();

    while (!(inputStudentID.length()==6))
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a student ID that is 6 characters");
        --timeout1;
        if( timeout1 == 0 ) {
            System.out.println("say something here");
            return;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Enter Module Mark: ");
    inputMark = in.nextInt();
    while (inputMark <0 || inputMark >100)
    {
        System.out.println("PLease enter a module mark between 0-100");
        --timeout2;
        if( timeout2 == 0 ) {
            System.out.println("say something here");
            return;
        }
    }
    addStudent(inputStudentID, inputMark);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("New student record has been " + 
                "successfully created");
    System.out.println();
    countRecords();

}
```